# Pendulum Mass Dampers and Buildings

Tags: resonance

So if a driving force is applied to a building containing a mass damper, what will happen under the following circumstance

If the mass dampers frequency is not equal to the resonance frequency of the building. Will the amplitude of the driving frequencies be significantly higher?

Is there a calculation for this?